# Android Live Wallpaper and main activity in apps list

Tags: android, android-activity, live-wallpaper

I just created a live wallpaper but i can't show it on the program list. The wallpaper apperas only in wallpaper list, by long pressing the home screen.

Is there a way to show the wallpaper on both screens: wallpaper list and program list?

I tried by setting an intent filter **action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />** in the manifest but the wallpaper doesn't compare.

```
     <activity
        android:name="Preferences"
        android:label="@string/description"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.WallpaperSettings"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.PREFERENCE" />
         </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

What should I use in the Manifest file to show the wallpaper on both screens?

Comment: Why would you want to have a launcher icon in the first place ?

Comment: I just want to have both options to laucnh the wallpaper: by longclick on home screen and by main activity (that launch preferences). The second option is faster to change the preferences of the wallpaper.

Comment: The user expects a launcher icon to take him to a view that has active content for consumption, not a view for changing settings. Would you really like an icon just for changing some settings ? If so, sorry, but you're missing the whole point of a launcher and how the system works. It's just bad practice. Put the settings in the action overflow menu in the set wallpaper activity. That's where it's supposed to be.